# Is there some software to search for photos based on a GPS coordinate?

Tags: images, photography, privacy, gps, search-engine

I have done this:

1. Determined the standard GPS coordinates for a spot right outside where I live.

I'm trying to do the following:

2. Input this into some kind of search engine.
3. Get back photos whose metadata shows that they were taken within X meters (preferably, I get to pick the maximum distance) of that geographical point.

As I understand it, people take photos where this info is baked in all the time, with their phones and whatnot. It would be really interesting to fetch "local" photos for any location I pick in my little map system.

Of course, I have many times tried searching for location names and whatnot, but never find anything relevant. For example, Instagram's "location" feature I have found useless. Likewise, entering a place name in something like DuckDuckGo's image search doesn't result in anything useful.

Is there such a thing? If not, is there something which technically prevents this? I mean, if they can build a feature which bakes this kind of sensitive information into photos, they can probably let me easily search for them as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Flickr. Unfortunately it search only between photos added to the map in flickr itself. Example URL is:

https://www.flickr.com/map/?fLat=41.893879&fLon=12.484121&zl=17

(coordinates are example)

You can also use google maps and check if someone upload photo(s) on particular coordinates (enter the coordinates in search field)

Comment: I may have lived under a rock for the last 20 years, but I have never heard of Flickr or anyone using it. So it must not be very big.

Comment: @MR, it was very big, now I have no information. Flickr was one of the first image upload web sites (for photographers). I use it from 2006

Answer (score 0):

Photo Sieve, photosieve.com , lets you search photos with valid gps coordinates by selecting a location and zoom level on a map.  It's not a specific range in meters but you can approximate by centering the location on the map and selecting an appropriate zoom level

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).